# Why does Zend Framework's $this->_redirect($url, array('code'=>301)) result in a 302 code?

Tags: zend-framework, redirect, http-status-code-301

When I call:

```
$this->_redirect($url, array('code'=>301));
```

I get redirected, but the http code is 302 instead of 301. Any idea why?

Comment: I just tested this and it worked fine for me (ZF 1.11). What version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that using the _redirect method will always set the code to a 302. If you'd like to manually change the response code, use a [redirector](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.redirector) instead.

Comment: $this->_redirector = $this->_helper->getHelper('Redirector');
    $this->_redirector->setCode(301);
made it work

Answer (score 3):

> _redirect($url, array $options = array()): redirect to another location. This method takes a URL and an optional set of options. By
>   default, it performs an HTTP 302 redirect.

try setting redirect code to 301 using:

```
$this->_helpers->redirector->setCode(301);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/Redirector.php: _redirect called $this->getCode(); getCode() is simple getter for $this->_code; _code initialized with 302.